# Uploading files over HTTP fails on iOS 8.0.0 GM Safari

Tags: ios, safari, mobile-safari, ios8

**UPDATE:** 
Confirmed: This has been fixed on the **iOS 8.0.2** update.

Using PUT/POST to upload file(s) over HTTP seems to get stuck on *Sending Request Headers* on mobile Safari on iOS 8 GM build.

I have an [example here](http://exampleuploader.projects.fm):

- Open an HTTP monitor on your desktop and route your iOS 8 device
  through it
- Login
- Add a file
- Hit Upload
- It gets stuck on Initializing (which is sending request headers)

This is the case even on http://m.facebook.com
- Try to add a photo to your status and it fails.

This *only* happens when the request contains a file. This is reproducible irrespective of having *multiple* enabled/disabled in the file input. Uploads work fine on Chrome on iOS 8.

Did anyone else experience this too? Is there a way to successfully send files over HTTP on iOS 8 Safari?

Comment: Seems to work in ios simulator (from Xcode 6). Are you seeing this on real device?

Comment: Yes I was trying on an iPhone and an iPod

Comment: Correct, this is a bug in iOS8. However, when pinning the website to your home screen and then starting it from there (run as single app) will work strangely enough.

Comment: @Bjorn True - I was able to upload when launching my "web-app" from the home screen.

Comment: I can't replicate this trick when pinning facebook for example.

Comment: @NikoRoberts The site needs to have the meta: `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` to work.

Comment: The apple-mobile-web-app-capable thing doesn't solve it for me unfortunately. (I am using jquery-file-upload.)

Comment: Any idea when this will be fixed

Comment: @tim No one knows, other than Apple, and they will definitely not be commenting on this.

Comment: Another find is that if your site is loaded in uiwebview (lets say some one open it on facebook) the upload will work.

Comment: @GuySchlider But only if either the file input element contains a multiple attribute OR the app creating the webview was compiled with the iOS8 SDK.  https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1283

Comment: The apple-mobile-web-app-capable thing does solve for us (using jquery-file-upload)

Comment: This issue appears to be fixed in iOS 8.0.1, along with a long-standing 0-sized video bug (https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/990)

Comment: Note that, while this was fixed in 8.0.1, the update was aborted.  So, many people are still affected by this bug.  http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/09/10/ios8-presents-serious-issues-that-prevent-file-uploading/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This was a bug in iOS 8.0.0 and was fixed in 8.0.2. The file body is not included in the request payload, but `Content-Length` is set as if it is.

See blog post *[File uploads appear to be broken in Safari on iOS 8](http://blog.uploadcare.com/post/97884147203/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari)*.

Comment: This has been fixed on iOS 8.0.1 according to the release notes.

Comment: we cannot confirm this yet as 8.0.1 is pulled (has some more serious bugs:). I'll update the answer when everything works out.

Comment: After updating to 8.0.2, it works now on iPhone5c. But still not working on either iPad3 nor iPhone6.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** Apple released iOS 8.0.2 yesterday and has fixed the upload bug.

File upload are broken in iOS 8.0. All files uploaded in Mobile Safari return 0-sized [1].

Hopefully this gets fixed by Apple in the next release. It seems like it is not affecting home screen webapps though:

> File uploads are broken!! Every file upload is not working, you can select a file or take a picture and after that JavaScript will not get any data, as well as the server on a POST upload through HTML or XMLHttpRequest upload. The problem doesn’t seem to apply for home screen webapps.

Source: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios8-iphone6-web-developers-designers

[1] http://blog.fineuploader.com/2014/09/10/ios8-presents-serious-issues-that-prevent-file-uploading/

Comment: The issue was indeed fixed in 8.0.1, as was [another long-standing issue that prevents videos from being uploaded](https://github.com/widen/fine-uploader/issues/990).  But the 8.0.1 update was aborted by Apple due to serious regressions.  There is no known planned release date for 8.0.2, but I suspect it will be weeks before another update.

Comment: I will be updating the Fine Uploader blog post linked in the answer here shortly.

Answer (score 6):

We're seeing similar issues in WordPress. All iOS8 GM uploads lead to 408 (http status, timeouts). Strangely enough, iOS8b5 was leading to error-500. Uploads are peachy under 7.1.*.

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29602#comment:17

Comment: I'm not surprised the server-side function is not triggered on iOS 8 because the upload seems to hang at _sending request headers_ which means no data was event sent to the server to begin with.

Comment: same here. Bug is being tracked apparently... this better be fixed in the final release :/

Comment: Well this is not fixed on the iOS8 release that came out yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the file upload works fine on IOS 8 (safari) if the image comes from screen shot and not from the iphone camera. For example, if you take a photo from you camera on iphone and try to upload the file via browser ( input type=file), it will send an empty data
src: "data:,"

while if you send the same image to your email and download it from your email and upload it again it works or if you take a screen shot photo it works as below
src: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD/7QA4UGhvdG9zaG9wIDMuMAA4QklNBAQAAAAAAAA4QklNBCUAAAAAABDUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+/8AAEQgGYATIAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkK....#
..."

Any idea or hint please us know.
Angluar JS is being used for file upload and NodeJS on the server 
Regards,
Alan Mehio