# Uploading from iphone through php script

Tags: php, ios, iphone

I have a php script that facilitates uploading of files (jpgs & movie files).

Php script:
http://pastebin.com/sA6Ewciq

However, when using a iphone with safari & chrome, it will successfully upload jpgs while not uploading it's *.MOV format. The server will receive a 0 size of the file, so it connects and creates the file with correct filename, but no data transfer occurs.

This works perfectly fine on Android, Desktops. If I copy the .MOV file that does not work on the iphone and copy to the android it uploads successfully.

This tells me that the php script works right (98% sure) all permissions are correct, but there is something about the MOV format that does not permit copying where JPG's are allowed?

Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

This question appears to have been downvoted several times (I don't know why) despite this being a legitimate issue.
Further searching brought up these answers relating to this exact issue, however, it has not been greatly addressed while using php.

https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/990

[Uploading files over HTTP fails on iOS 8.0.0 GM Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790873/uploading-files-over-http-fails-on-ios-8-0-0-gm-safari)

http://blog.uploadcare.com/post/97884147203/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari

It appears the cause is a malfunction with ios requests causing it to fail when the upload script permits multiple file selection as it sends incorrect get requests.

> We can see that the request length should be 134573 bytes (Content-Length header), but as the file is absent from the request and the real length is only 176 bytes.

This explains why the file is 0 bytes but doesn't explain why jpgs work. Oh well

This affects ios 7.* and 8.0.0

The "fix" involves either using ios 6, or updating to ios 8.0.2 which fixes it in safari but not in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Videos are larger files then images therefore will require longer time execution.

Because an iPhone has less ressources then a typical PC it will take even longer.

When the maximum time is reached, `PHP` will just quit leaving half-baked uploads behind.

The solution is to extend the maximum execution time.

You do this in PHP ini

```
max_execution_time = 60;in second
```

But you don't have to, you can override it with the following code:

```
set_time_limit(60);//in second
```

Don't forget to reboot the server if you make the change in `php.ini`

Comment: Mine is set at max_execution_time = 180
since it completes the script within a few seconds, I do not see this being the problem. I do not have set_time_limit in my config, since the max time is at 180 already, would this actually benefit?

Comment: @Miati 60 is just an example, you need to put as much time needed use `set_time_limit(0)` for unlimited just to test if you don't know. `set_time_limit` is php code in the script